# Custom Multi Select Tool in jQuery with Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, multi-select

I have a requirement to build a custom multiselect box with jquery that will be used in an MVC app in .NET.

The only requirement is to be able to extend an existing drop down input (multi select) box with some kind of naming convention, and write out a list of check boxes. The data source is a generic list of objects we can bind using a model.

Here is an example:

[image]

My question is about the best approach for this. I’d hate to reinvent the wheel if there is a good solution out there. I could not find one. If I must build from scratch, my initial thought is to position a DIV full of check boxes directly below the existing drop down input to be extended. Positioning would be the “fun” part of that solution.

Could anyone else offer alternative implementation ideas, existing controls that would suite my needs, or examples of similar functionality I could look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like exactly what you're searching for: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/